# How to print to PDF with Excel VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pdf, vba

As the title suggests... I'm looking to expand my automating to include directly printing to PDF. The macro(s) I have written already formats the print area and page setup as I need it.  But when I go to record my macros nothing for printing, changing printers or saving to file is captured.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I could even get by if it just required a save location prompt. The file name I would imagine could be auto-generated by grabbing existing info within the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Excel 2010 and above, then Excel provides you with in internal add-in which allows you to save the file as PDF format.
Use the following code in your macro to save your file as PDF

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        True
```

Here you can replace the path  **C:\Users\46506090\Desktop\Book1.pdf** and file name to your liking.

Edit: If you intend to publish the entire workbook as PDF and not just the sheet you are working on just replace Active**Sheet**.ExportAsFixedFormat to Active**Workbook**.ExportAsFixedFormat

Comment: Will I be able to customize the filename & location based on other content within the worksheet or previously defined by another sub?  Also, will this overwrite any file names already present at that location or give me a prompt to rename?  Isn't the default usually a (1) after the filename to avoid overwriting existing files?

Comment: To add to this answer: In my version of this, it saves the PDF file in the same location as the file being printed. `fPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, ".") - 1) & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"`

Comment: @dasMetzger Sure, you can customize it. Prasanna hard-coded it but you can change it to a variable and then set that variable anywhere you like. You could even put this snippet into a function with the file path as an argument so you can call it elsewhere.

Comment: If you want to use the same filename as the Excel file is - you can add @EngineerToast code